# How to check a time is between two times in python

Tags: python

For example if I have

test_case1: (9:00 - 16:00) and

test_case2: (21:30 - 4:30)

that is, it works whether the first or second number is bigger than the other.

Comment: What do you consider under 'works' - both of those can give vastly different time differences in dependence of which one you take into consideration first. Is the first time always considered as a preceding one to the second time?

Comment: Very simply, `start_time < some_time < end_time`

Comment: Eg. for test_case1, 11:00 is true, 17:00 is false

Comment: @DeepSpace that assumes test_case1 that is the second number is greater than the first number

Comment: @Mat.S This is given by definition "between two times in python" (if `y` is "between `x` and `z` then it's implied that `x > z` or `z > x`), Or you simply don't explain yourself good enough.

Comment: @Mat.S The question has no answer if you don't specify *how* you are representing the times.

Comment: Please post the code you're using now, and examples of cases where it does and doesn't work as you expect. If you don't have code and test cases, it is premature to post your question here.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use pure lexicographical string comparison if you zero-fill your times - then all you need is to determine if the second time is 'smaller' than the first time and for that special case check both days, e.g.:

```
def is_between(time, time_range):
    if time_range[1] < time_range[0]:
        return time >= time_range[0] or time <= time_range[1]
    return time_range[0] <= time <= time_range[1]

print(is_between("11:00", ("09:00", "16:00")))  # True
print(is_between("17:00", ("09:00", "16:00")))  # False
print(is_between("01:15", ("21:30", "04:30")))  # True
```

This will also work with time tuples (e.g. `(9, 0)`) instead of strings if that's how you represent your time. It will even work with most time objects.

Answer (score 4):

You can create `datetime.datetime` objects and compare

```
>>> start = datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 23, 9, 0)
>>> end = datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 23, 16, 0) 
>>> start < datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 23, 11, 0) < end
True
>>> start < datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 23, 18, 0) < end
False
```

If all times are on the same day, you could simply create `datetime.time`s

```
>>> start = datetime.time(9, 0)
>>> end = datetime.time(16, 0) 
>>> start < datetime.time(11, 0) < end
True
>>> start < datetime.time(18, 0) < end
False
```

Comment: That's a bit of an overkill and it still doesn't deal with the fact that OP wants to check ranges that span over two days as well.

Comment: It totally deals with it, as long as he specifies datetimes. If he does not the question is somewhat I'll defined.

Comment: No it does not. If `start = datetime.time(21, 30)` and `end = datetime.time(4, 30)` (the next day) as in OP's `test_case2`, if the time you're looking for is `time = datetime.time(2, 0)` - `start < time < end` will evaluate to `False` even tho it is within that time range.

Comment: As said twice by now (and used in half my answer), that's fine as long as you use `datetime` instead of `time`.

Comment: Not here to argue, but the OP didn't mention dates even once - he wants to compare times. Times cannot be compared in a range without taking into the account that they might span over two days which is what the OP was precisely asking how to do. Your answer doesn't answer the OPs question.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply convert the 'times' to minutes per day:

```
def minutesPerDay(tme):
    hours, minutes = tme.split(':')
    return (hours*60)+minutes

def checkTime(tme, tmeRange):
    return minutesPerDay(tmeRange[0]) < minutesPerDay(tme) < tmeRange[1]


print(checkTime('11:00', ('09:00', '16:00')))  # True
print(checkTime('17:00', ('09:00', '16:00')))  # False
```

Comment: This will fail in the OP's second test case (time range spanning over two days), e.g. `checkTime("02:00", ("21:30", "04:30"))`.